# Population values not updating in deSolve in R

Tags: r, ode

I am working on a model with different compartments for different age groups and smokers/non-smokers. I thought all was going well, but when I started to dig into the output, I see that the populations are not updating at each time step as I anticipated. I used the debugger to step through the code, and indeed, it keeps using the initial stock size for every time step, so I end up with a constant change in population sizes, which is incorrect.

There are 200 stocks in the model, so I don't want to paste the whole thing in, but here are the pieces I think may be most relevant.

```
smokdiff <- function(times,init,parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(init,parameters)), {

    dns00 <- births - ns00*mort[1,1] - ns00/5 
    dns05 <- ns00/5 - ns05*mort[1,2] - ns05/5

...

    list(c(dns00,dns05,dns10,...
 })
}

times <- seq(0,tf,dt)
init <- c(ns00,ns05,ns10,...
parameters <- c(births,mort,init15,utinit15,ltinit15)
out <- ode(func=smokdiff, times=times, y=init, parms=parameters)
```

Here is a sample of the output for the ns00 population:

```
     time       1
[1,]    0 9244769
[2,]    1 9217034
[3,]    2 9189300
[4,]    3 9161566
[5,]    4 9133832
[6,]    5 9106097
```

As you can see, it decreases by ~27,734 each step, which is only correct for the first step (e.g. it's supposed to decrease by 22,104 in the second step).

I have compared to multiple models I've found online, and I can't spot what it is I'm doing wrong. I've also tried other "methods" in the ode call, but they all display the constant change. I'm beginning to worry that I have some basic misunderstanding about how this is supposed to work. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

SOLUTION:
The initial states have to be defined in a 'state=value' manner. Simply putting a variable with the value in it is insufficient. Here is a small working example:

```
library(deSolve)
smokdiff <- function(times,init,parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(init,parameters)), {

    dns00 <- births - ns00*mort[1] - ns00/5 
    dns05 <- ns00/5 - ns05*mort[2] - ns05/5
    dns10 <- ns05/5 - ns10*mort[3] - ns10/5

    list(c(dns00,dns05,dns10))
 })
}

mort <- c(0.003, 0.001, 0.001)
ns00 <- 9000000; ns05 <- 8500000; ns10 <- 8500000
births <- ns00/5
times <- seq(0,50,0.25)
init <- c(ns00=ns00,ns05=ns05,ns10=ns10)
parameters <- c(births,mort)
out <- ode(func=smokdiff, times=times, y=init, parms=parameters)
```

Comment: There's so many undefined variable floating around it's hard to figure out what is being specified and what is being estimated/projected. I don't see any evidence that you have read this sentence in the help page for `?ode`: `"The return value of func should be a list, whose first element is a vector containing the derivatives of y with respect to time, and whose next elements are global values that are required at each point in times."`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I was trying not to paste everything in since it's hundreds of lines, but I believe I've satisfied that requirement. The return value is a list, with the derivatives of each initial value, in the exact order. It is the piece of the code above: list(c(dns00,dns05,dns10,...

I have attempted it as that and as return(list(c(dns00,dns05,dns10,...

Neither seems to do it.

Comment: I figured it out. It is my line:

init <- c(ns00,ns05,ns10,...

I have to put ns00=ns00, and so on, for all the variables. I'm not sure why that is--what the difference is between that and just ns00, but it works. 

Question: Should I leave this up for others' reference, or should I delete it since I answered my own question?

Comment: It should be useful to future users. It would be even more useful if you answered with a small working example. A named vector is different than an unnamed one.

Comment: If you do that, you can give yourself a checkmark after a suitable interval, and I'll join you.

Answer (score 1):

A note for any passing readers - this comes down to how `ode()` and `with()` interact.

`with()` goes looking for variable names, and if they are not present, fails *silently*.

That's why the solution above works, it gives `with()` those variable names, but this comes down to poor design in the `with()` function really.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, +1 :)