# deSolve package in R, variable not updating

Tags: r, ode

I am using R and the package deSolve to solve a set of differential equations. The variables are WC and C (water content and concentration in soil layers). The number of soil layers can be change in the code which is as follow:

```
numboxes <- 1                   # Number of soil layers
delx <- rep(1,numboxes)     # Thickness of soil layers (cm)
delt <- 1   
bulk<-0.5;FC<-0.4;Ks<-0.03;Sat<-0.8;Wres<-0.1;kbio=0.01;kd=10  #parameters
## the model
SPEC <- function(t,state,parms) {
    with(as.list(c(state,parms)),{
    ifelse (WC>=Wres, perc <- (WC*delx*10*bulk-FC*delx*10*bulk)*(1-exp(
    -Ks/(Sat*delx*10*bulk-FC*delx*10*bulk))), perc <-0)
    #
    dWC <- -diff(c(0,perc))*24/(10*delx*bulk)
    dC <- -kbio*C
    list(c(dWC,dC),perc=perc)
    })
}
```

Then the function is solve using the deSlove package:

```
WC <-rep(0.5,times=numboxes)
C <- rep(20,times=numboxes)
state <- c(WC=WC,C=C)
times <- seq(from=1, to=5, by=delt)
out <- as.data.frame(ode(times=times,y=state,func=SPEC,parms=0,method="rk4"))
```

For a single soil layer (numboxes=1) everything works well and the results are:

```
  time        WC        C        perc
1    1 0.5000000 20.00000 0.007444030
2    2 0.4699599 19.80100 0.005207836
3    3 0.4489439 19.60397 0.003643397
4    4 0.4342411 19.40891 0.002548917
5    5 0.4239550 19.21579 0.001783219
```

However, when I increase the number of soil layers (numboxes=2 for example), the solver run but the results are not correct. For two layers:

```
  time       WC1 WC2   C1   C2      perc1      perc2
1    1 0.5000000 0.5 20.0 20.0 0.00744403 0.00744403
2    2 0.4642687 0.5 19.8 19.8 0.00744403 0.00744403
3    3 0.4285373 0.5 19.6 19.6 0.00744403 0.00744403
4    4 0.3928060 0.5 19.4 19.4 0.00744403 0.00744403
5    5 0.3570746 0.5 19.2 19.2 0.00744403 0.00744403
```

The results for the concentration in the two soil layers (C1 and C2) are correct and identical to the result of the single layer.
The computed water content is however not correct (the result for the first layer should be identical to the simulation using a single layer). It seams that to calculate the percolation (perc) the solver is only using the initial value of WC (0.5) hence the same value is computed every iteration (perc1 and perc2 always equal to 0.007 which is correct for a WC=0.5).

Strangly it was not the case when I used a single layer. This problem seams to be similar to what was reported here:
[Population values not updating in deSolve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369877/population-values-not-updating-in-desolve-in-r)
However, I am defining the initial values in a "state=value" manner and I am still facing the updating issue. Any ideas how I could solve that and why I am facing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the assignment to `perc` outside the `ifelse`.

```
perc <- ifelse(WC >= Wres,
               (WC*delx*10*bulk - FC*delx*10*bulk)*
               (1 - exp(-Ks/(Sat*delx*10*bulk - FC*delx*10*bulk))),
               0)
```

I don't even know what doing the assignment inside the `ifelse` will do.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I moved the assignment outside of ifelse.The results are identical to what I posted above: if I use a single layer everything is computed appropriatly, with 2 layers "perc" is computed using only the initial WC value of 0.5

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that you defined your state variables wrong. Run your code and then

```
state
```

You see, that the name is not WC and C, but WC1 WC2 C1 and C2
Your differential equation needs only W and C as state variables.

```
state <- c(WC = 0.5, C = 20)
```

This gives your expected result!

BTW: It's clearer when you put all your parameters in a vector "parms"

```
parms <- c(
   bulk = 0.5,
   FC = 0.4,
   Ks = 0.03,
   Sat = 0.8,
   Wres = 0.1,
   kbio = 0.01,
   kd = 10)
```

and then use:

```
 out <- as.data.frame(ode(times=times, y=state, func=SPEC, parms=parms, method="rk4"))
```

Best wishes,
Johannes